# C++ - Moving the function to another .hpp file requires forward declaration at separate file that uses the function

Tags: c++

I had a working code structured as follows:

- `a.hpp` has helper functions for random generation.
- `b.hpp` has the other helper functions.
- `c.hpp` is a class definition and uses random generation function from `a.hpp`.

I wanted to combine `a.hpp` and `b.hpp` as a general `Utility.hpp` file. I have copied every function of `b.hpp` into `a.hpp` and renamed the file into `Utility.hpp`. In `c.hpp` and the other files, I have changed the `#include` statement accordingly.

However, when I compile the `main.cpp` using g++ (Rev4, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.2.0, I get the following error now:

> c.hpp error: 'randomUnitVector' was not declared in this scope

I have the same `randomUnitVector` called in the main as well, and there is no problem.

`a.hpp`: has helper functions for random generation

```
glm::vec3 randomUnitVector()
{
    auto p = randomVector(-1, 1);
    return glm::normalize(p);
}
```

`b.hpp`: has another set of helper functions

`Utility.hpp`: has everything in `b` and `a`

`c.hpp`: is a Class definition file

```
...
#include "Utility.hpp"
...

/* if I forward declare as follows the problem is solved, but there
were no need for decleration prior to file change. */
glm::vec3 randomUnitVector();

class M {...};

class L : public M {
    ...
    virtual glm::vec3 getReflection(const glm::vec3 &intersect_point, const glm::vec3 &surface_normal) const override
    {
        return intersect_point + surface_normal + randomUnitVector();
    }
    ...
};
...
```

I can overcome this problem by forward declaring `randomUnitVector` at the beginning of the `c.hpp`, but I am wondering why I need to redeclare the function in `c.hpp` just because I have moved the original declaration from `b.hpp` to `a.hpp` renamed to `Utility.hpp`.

Comment: I find it worrying that you have all your code inside header files. That's not how C++ works.

Comment: Rather than just describing the files, it would have been much more useful if you had shown the actual files, and the updated files.

Comment: @SebastianRedl well on the positive side, header-only libraries don't need to be recompiled after having been modified.

Comment: @Sebastian Redl, when I am coding my own project, I tend to separate the cpp and header files. This code is given to me. I am just trying to modify some parts, but this behavior made me curious.

Comment: is `Utility.hpp` in the same folder as `c.hpp` ?

Comment: @Giogre, yes, all the files are in the same folder except the glm library for which I give the include path through the g++.

Comment: Maybe `Utility.hpp` cannot find `glm::normalize()`? Have you included <glm> in `Utility.hpp`, or only in `c.hpp`?

Comment: @Giogre both files have the glm included. I have directly carried all includes and functions of `a.hpp` and `b.hpp` to `Utility.hpp` without duplicates. As you might ask further, the header files I have contain include guard `#pragma once` as well. The content is completely same yet, this behavior occurs. I am aware, this is not an issue at this point, and I have a workaround, but I am just curious about the reason.